# Question on implicit UNNEST and the effects of aliasing, or not, the unnested array field

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to understand the finer points of implicit `UNNEST`. Most especially, how the unnested field is referred to if you don't alias it.

### EXAMPLE 1

```
WITH
  arry AS (
  SELECT
    ['foo','bar'] AS f1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    ['a', 'b'] AS f1)

SELECT
  f1
FROM
  arry
CROSS JOIN
  arry.f1
```

returns as expected:

```
ROW         f1
1           foo
2           bar
3           a
4           b
```

But if you alias `arry.f1` as such:

### EXAMPLE 2

```
WITH
  arry AS (
  SELECT
    ['foo','bar'] AS f1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    ['a', 'b'] AS f1)

SELECT
  f1
FROM
  arry
CROSS JOIN
  arry.f1 AS alias
```

you get back:

```
ROW         f1
1           foo
            bar
2           foo
            bar
3           a
            b
4           a
            b
```

Trying the following shed some light on what is happening:

### EXAMPLE 3

```
WITH
  arry AS (
  SELECT
    ['foo','bar'] AS f1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    ['a', 'b'] AS f1)

SELECT
  f1,  
  arry.f1 as arry_f1,
  alias
FROM
  arry
INNER JOIN
  arry.f1 AS alias
```

You get back:

```
ROW    f1     arry_f1   alias
1      foo    foo       foo
       bar    bar
2      foo    foo       bar
       bar    bar
3      a      a         a
       b      b
4      a      a         b
       b      b
```

So obviously, the `f1` in my first 2 select clauses do not refer to the same thing. In:

```
SELECT
  f1
FROM
  arry
INNER JOIN
  arry.f1
```

`f1` in the `SELECT` is referring to the implicitely unnested `arry.f1`.

In the second case where I alias,

```
SELECT
  f1
FROM
  arry
INNER JOIN
  arry.f1 AS alias
```

`f1` refers to the array field `f1` of the `arry` table whereas `alias` refers to the unnested `alias.f1` field in the `SELECT` as the third example makes clear.

I don't understand why `f1` can be assumed to be what it is in example 1:

```
SELECT
  f1
FROM
  arry
INNER JOIN
  arry.f1
```

Should't it be ambiguous as it could be referring to field `f1` of `arry` (which is an array) or the implicitely unnested `arry.f1`?

It certainly threw me off when I saw the results.  I see nowhere in the documentation where it says how the naming and scoping works with implicit unnesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't understand why f1 can be assumed to be what it is in example 1:

My few cents ...

*Even though, I am using that feature a lot and for quite a time to simplify/streamline code  - I am not sure if it is a “designed feature” or just “feature by a chance”*

So, when you use `JOIN arry.f1` it is being treated as a table (sub-table of arry table) – I think because of pattern `dataset.table` here. As such each and every element in f1 array is treated as a value in separate row (with still JOIN is applied on parent row level)